# How to get rid of x and up/down arrow elements of a input date?

Tags: html, css, input

[image]

The only thing that I need showing up in the box there is the orange triangle, and I am not sure if I need CSS or something else to get rid of the two elements to the left of the triangle.

Is there a way to do so? I am just using the input type `date`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5M2PD/1/

Comment: I want to keep the arrow, but get rid of the other 2

Answer (score 94):

Use the pseudo-class `-webkit-inner-spin-button` to style it specific for webkit-based browsers:

http://jsfiddle.net/5M2PD/2/

```css
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to change the style of the dropdown arrow, use the pseudo-class `-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator`:

```css
input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
```

To eliminate the clear button, set the input to required:

http://jsfiddle.net/5M2PD/3/

```html
<input type="date" required="required" />
```

Comment: Thanks. but the x element still remains, i am not sure what exactly it is called, so I don't really know what to search so find the appropriate webkit name for it.

Comment: Add `required="required"` to the input element

Comment: Unfortunately, though...if you don't actually want it to be required, there isn't really any way to remove the clear button in webkit browsers.

Comment: Thank you!. Also if I wanted to replace ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator with a downwards chevron, would that be possible? I am looking at this: http://davidwalsh.name/webkit-appearance

and there doesnt seem to be a helpful option

Comment: are there mozilla equivalents? nm, firefox doesn't add wierd stuff in there.

Comment: @saluce there is a way now, see vee's answer

Answer (score 47):

To remove the clear button, use this:

```
::-webkit-clear-button
{
    display: none; /* Hide the button */
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* turn off default browser styling */
}
```

As a side note, to do this in IE10+ ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465740.aspx)), use this:

```
::-ms-clear { }
```

Note that this one works on `<input type="text" />`, since IE now places a clear button there as well.

To style the rest of the date control in WebKit browsers, I would recommend having a look at [this link](http://tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#input_date). To summarize it, you can play with the following pseudo classes:

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit { }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper { }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-text { }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field { }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field { }
::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field { }
::-webkit-inner-spin-button { }
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { }
```

I would also highly recommend using the following in order to turn off the default browser styles; I've found this to be especially useful when working with mobile browsers:

```
input[type="date"]
{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Can I style the `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` class to use my own image instead of the triangle?

Answer (score 4):

Chrome (v79):

```
input[type='date']::-webkit-clear-button,
input[type='date']::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    display: none;
}
```

Firefox (v73):

Firefox has only the clear button for date inputs. To remove it, the field should be made required.

```
<input type=’date’ required=’required’ />
```

Safari (v13):

Safari doesn’t support type=’date’.

Answer (score -1):

Removes (x) on input type date. Only works for Internet Explorer.

```css
.input_base input[type="date"]::-ms-clear {
  display: none;
}
```