# How to disable datepicker arrow for a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker

I have been looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320615/disable-native-datepicker-in-google-chrome) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418289/remove-background-arrow-from-date-input-in-google-chrome-v20) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954966/how-to-get-rid-of-x-and-up-down-arrow-elements-of-a-input-date) and they have all been very helpful in getting rid of the small arrow on a **datepicker** using:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { display: none; }
```

However, I have multiple date fields in one of my views and I would like to only **disable the datepicker arrow for the fields that have a specific class**.

I would like to do something like:

```
input[class="buttonOnly"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { display: none; }
```

But it does not seem to be working. I'm hoping this is a simple syntax issue but I can't seem  to find any examples. Is something like this frowned upon or am I just missing something?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: instead of input[class="buttonOnly"] use input.buttonOnly

Comment: @Hoyen Yes that worked beautifully! I knew it would be something as simple as that. I feel quite silly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.class` selector along with with `attribute` selector

```css
input[type="date"].disabled::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" class="disabled">

<input type="date">
```