# Center date in input field with date type

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to center date in `input`, not `input` inside `div`. If I do centering, it centers date inside of part of `input` because there is a right-hand side panel for choosing a date based on a calendar, which resizes dependently of input width.

**Small code snippet for demonstration:**

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div>
      <input type='date' class='center' value='2006-01-01' width='100'>
    </div>
```

I tried to force centering with ignoring the right panel. Then the date is not fully visible.

Another approach was to find the size of calendar choice panel, and I did not find any mechanism both on StackOverflow and Internet to calculate the width, plus I did experiments with a ruler to find the proportion, and it also did not work.

The last, I tried searching into StackOverflow and did not find any similar questions.

In my project, I use plain JavaScript, jQuery, HTML, and CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, there is nothing wrong with the `text-align: center` part, it is working as expected, the problem is that the buttons on the right side of the input (the ones that appear when you hover over the input) need to take up some space as well.

So, you will have to hide those!
You can use the `required="required"`attribute on your `<input>` element if you want to remove the "x" button, and these 2 CSS rules to control the arrows and the dropdown (however, do note how the nice date-picker doesn't appear anymore and you have to type down a date using your keyboard when you use the `input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` rule):

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
    }

input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}



input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type='date' class='center' value='2006-01-01' width='100' required="required">
    </div>
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17954966/how-to-get-rid-of-x-and-up-down-arrow-elements-of-a-input-date) question if you are interested in more of this.

Or you can just use the [JQuery date-picker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) if you want to.

Comment: Is there any lightweight framework solution which will work as I expect it to be?

Comment: @Taurus, actually I cannot do default date-picker bigger because I have in a column many input fields with different types, so I wanted to customize default date-picker. Do you have any ideas if there is a way to calculate hidden right side buttons?

Comment: @Taurus, your answer was exactly what I looked. How did you come to such solution?

Comment: @DmitriyChasovskoy I just googled "html datepicker remove buttons" and the first result that popped up was the StackOverflow answer I linked you to in my answer.

Comment: @DmitriyChasovskoy Don't feel bad though, searching is tedious and stressful.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center an `<input>` inside a `<div>`, you need to apply `text-align: center` to the **`<div>`** element, not the `<input>`. This can be achieved by simply moving your class `.center` to the `<div>` instead:

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='center'>
  <input type='date' value='2006-01-01'>
</div>
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to center the text in an `<input type='date'>`, you first need to convert the input to a **block-level element** with `display: block`. Note that the `text-align` is relative to the dropdown caret and cross, so you might actually want to use `text-align: right` and a slightly larger `width` instead:

```css
.center {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type='date' class='center' value='2006-01-01'>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: No, I want to center date inside `input` field not `input` inside `div`. If my post was misleading for you,  can you possibly give me any suggestions how to improve wording?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think such input is not customizable the way you want. I suggest you to use JavaScript datepickers.

Comment: My apologies; based on the question I thought you wanted the `<input>` centralised in the `<div>`. I've updated my answer to additionally showcase how text can be centered in an `<input>` for a `date`.

Comment: Your edit does not work (on Firefox at least), it does not center the text inside the date type input field.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you **not** to use browser’s datepickers cause they’re not very reliable and cross-browser (many older browsers don’t support it).

[jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) is a great framework for these widgets, and you can completely customize the datepicker through CSS.

Note that you’ll need the base [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) framework for jQuery UI to work but it is very lightweight and I suggest you to use it even with other JavaScript codes in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding 'required', I recommend adding

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-clear-button
```

otherwise the 'x' still takes some space and it's not truely centered.